# How to send a header in Python with urllib2

Tags: python, json

I am trying to request an API from a site, if I did not send

> Accept: application/vnd.travis-ci.2+json

with the header, the response will come as an XML format. What I want is a JSON format. So, I need to send that header with the blow code.

```
url = 'https://api.example.org/books/title'
import json, urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
jsonString = response.read()
repo = json.loads(jsonString)
```

The above doesn't do anything, because `url` is being returned in xml format, unless I add `Accept: application/vnd.travis-ci.2+json` to the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a custom header using `request`. Also see the answer from Daniel Roseman who was faster giving the same answer.

```
 import urllib2
 request = urllib2.Request("https://api.example.org/books/title", headers={"Accept" : "application/vnd.travis-ci.2+json"})
 contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass header as below

```
request = urllib2.Request(url , headers={"Accept" : "application/json"})
```

**UPDATE**

```
url = 'https://api.example.org/books/title'
import json, urllib2
request = urllib2.Request(url , headers={"Accept" : "application/json"})
jsonString  = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: So, am I supposed to replace that line with one of my code? What do I do with the `request` var?

Comment: pass request to urlopen (response = urllib2.urlopen(request))

Comment: sorry, atleast your first one somewhat worked. but the second gives me nothing.

Comment: the first is showing me a serialized data, not a json response.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly with `urlopen`, but you can with `Request`.

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.travis-ci.2+json'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```